# Quantum Computation - Finding joint state given partial properties of two pairs of qubits

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

I have a problem I need to figure out how to solve for an exam in a few days and I'm struggling to find any advice online 
I need to find the joint state of two pairs of entangled qubits following the following two properties:

The joint state of A and B, ignoring normalization, is given as |00> + |11>

The joint state of B and C, again ignoring normalization, is also given as |00> + |11>

To solve this I either need to give an example of a state which fits these requirements or show it cannot exist but I'm unsure how to go about doing either of these

Any help would be greatly appreciated x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property of the von Neumann entropy known as strong subadditivity which states that for any tripartite system, we have

$$S(ABC) + S(B) \leq S(AB) + S(BC)$$

For your system, you have $S(B) = \log d$ as it is the maximally mixed state and $S(AB) = S(BC) = 0$ as they are pure states. Since the von Neumann entropy is nonnegative, $S(ABC) \geq 0$ so you will violate strong subadditivity.

Therefore, your state cannot exist.

Comment: See also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/218085/what-is-the-monogamy-principle-in-entanglement